# Count number of times a condition is met (Python)

Tags: python

I am coding a simple test that is supposed to count the number of times the user answered "yes" and "no". Here's my code:

```
questions = ["Are you happy?", "Did you shower?", "Are you Turkish?", "Are you bored?", "Do you have friends?"]   

yes = 0
no = 0

for each in questions:
    answers = input(each)
    if answers == "yes":
        yes =+ 1
    elif answers == "no":
       no =+ 1

print(yes, no)
```

After answering either "yes" or "no" the questions Python answers `Output: (0,0)`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The exact output I'm getting is here:

```
raflicky@raflicky-MacBookPro:~/enviroments$ python quiz.py
Are you happy?yes
Did you shower?no
Are you Turkish?yes
Are you bored?no
Do you have friends?yes
(0, 0)
```

Comment: What is it currently outputting that is indicating to you that something is wrong?

Comment: My bad, I'll edit it in a sec. It is giving me `Ouput: (0,0)`

Comment: You've written `=+` in two places where I believe you meant to write `+=`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Great point, but that would set yes and no to 1, whereas OP claims they are 0.

Comment: That could only mean that the conditions are never met. Which would mean input is always  neither yes nor no

Comment: Already changed `yes += 1` and `no += 1`. Still same result

Comment: @JohnZwinck Actually, copy pasting the code, the output I am getting is actually `(1, 1)`.  Which means the OP is inputting data that is never meeting the condition if they are getting `(0, 0)`

Comment: @RafaelMartínez What is the *exact* input you are putting it in to your code?

Comment: I just added it to the question @idjaw

Comment: @RafaelMartínez I just copy pasted your code, put in the exact inputs you did and my answer is `(1, 1)`. If I make the correction already indicated to use `+=`, the answer is the expected `3, 2`. So, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe there is another way to solve the problem? Perhaps trying something like `.append()` and printing at the end `len(yes), len(no)` or something that gives us the same output @idjaw

Comment: @RafaelMartínez The real problem right now is why is it when I copy paste your code, I am not getting the output you are getting? Something is not right on your end, because the code you are showing in your question is not behaving as you are stating. Beyond this, I am not sure what else to suggest. Try copy pasting this code in to a clean python file and run it on its own?

Comment: @idjaw thank you a lot for taking the interest in my question, really. I tried running it on this [online Python link](https://repl.it/languages/python3). If you copy paste the exact code and exact input it will give you only 1,1 instead of 3,2. What can I do to get 3,2??

Comment: @RafaelMartínez It was already explained in the comments, and there are two answers already posted addressing the issue. You have `=+` written, when it should be `+=`.

Comment: It finally worked, I usually ask better questions but I was really struggling with this. Bad day I guess, thank you really for bearing with me @idjaw

Comment: @RafaelMartínez All good. Glad to see you get it working. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rafael Martínez !

Your program inverts the augmented assign operator. It should be `+=` and not `=+`

For instance, your line

```
yes =+ 1
```

is actually setting 1 to the variable `yes`, not incrementing its previous value in one.

I did not know that was possible. Thanks for the interesting example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have =+ instead of +=. If you change it to +=,it will work